# Dequeue algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue, deque

**Write four O(1)-time procedures to insert elements into and delete elements from both ends of a deque constructed from an array.**

In my implementation I have maintained 4 pointers *front1,rear1,front2,rear2*.

Do you have any other algorithm with less pointers and O(1) complexity ? Please explain.

Comment: `having 4 functions each with O(1) ` what functions?

Comment: Please post your implementation.

Comment: Also, `I have maintained 4 pointers front1,rear1,front2,rear2.` - and where is the data stored?

Comment: @user3386109  **I am not sure about my algorithm implementation.**
Also I am not getting Queue-Empty and Queue-Full conditions.

Comment: That's fine, post it anyways and someone will help you improve it.

Comment: @user3386109 

//Initialize h1=t1=1;
 h2=t2=n;

full(A)
{
 if((t1==n/2+1 && h1==1) || (t2==n-n/2 && h2==n))
  "Overflow" and return 0;
 else 
  return 1;
}


empty(A)
{
 if(h1==t1 && h2==t2)
  "Underflow" and return 0;
 else
  return 1;
}



Enqueue1(A,x)
{
 if(full()==1)
 {
  A[t1]=x
  if(t1==n/2 && h1!=1)
   t1=1
  else 
   t1++
 }
}


Enqueue2(A,x)
{
 if(full()==1)
 {
  A[t2]=x
  if(t2==n/2+1 && h1!=n)
   t2=n
  else 
   t1--
 }
}

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common ways to implement a deque:

1. [Doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list): You implement a doubly linked list, and maintain pointers to the front and the end of the list. It is easy to both insert and remove the start/end of the linked list in `O(1)` time.
2. A circular dynamic array: In here, you have an array, which is treated as circular array (so elements in index=`arr.length-1` and index=`0` are regarded as adjacent).

   In this implementation you hold the index number of the "head", and the "tail". Adding element to the "head" is done to index `head-1` (while moving the head backward), and adding element to the tail is done by writing it to index `tail+1`.

   This method is amortized `O(1)`, and has better constants then the linked list implementation. However, it is not "strict worst case" `O(1)`, since if the number of elements exceeds the size of the array, you need to reallocate a new array and move elements from the old one to the new one. This takes `O(n)` time (but needs to be done after at least `O(n)` operations), and thus it is `O(1)` amortized analysis, but can still fall to `O(n)` from time to time.

Comment: Can you provide me code for this implementation please ?
Also according to above amortized implementation if queue-full conditions are front=rear then 'overflow'. What if ENQUEUE and DEQUEUE are randomly called ? Then Queue-empty and Queue-full conditions might fail !

Comment: @avantika: This isn't a code writing service. You should attempt to write code for the algorithm he described, and if you have trouble post a question that includes the code and a description of the problem that you're having.

Comment: @Jim okay..I'm new in here.Thanks for telling me.